# convert two different dictionaries in single dictionary with single line of code in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Python 3.5+

```
A = {'a':10, 'b':20}

B = {'c':100, 'd':200}
```

The answer should be:

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 100, 'd': 200}
```

But in a single line of python code

Comment: result = `{**A, **B}`

Comment: Or `A.update(B)`

Comment: `{**A, **B}` will overwrite keys if they are repeated, fyi

Comment: “Overwrite keys if they are repeated” - as dictionaries can’t have duplicated keys, any method for merging dictionaries has this problem/feature that one or the other must be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

In Python its as simple as that:

Answer = `{**A, **B}`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```py
A.update(B)

print(A)
```